# how correctly add HTML tags to setMessage

Tags: magento-1.9

i have this code

```
 $result->setMessage(
                                Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('This item is not available and will be placed in a backorder queue. Please refer to the <a href="#">Backorder info page</a> for details on how this order will be processed.', ($backorderQty * 1))
                            );
```

but result this code:
[image]

how correctly add HTML tags?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes:

`__("You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the confirmation link or <a href=""%1"">click here</a> for a new link.")`